# Install rocks without reloging after 'apt-get install luarocks'

Tags: lua

I'm trying to script an install which needs luarocks and a couple of rocks installed.

After: `sudo apt-get -y install luarocks`

But before I relog, If I try: `luarocks install loadcaffe`

I get

```
Error: Your user does not have write permissions in /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
-- you may want to run as a privileged user or use your local tree with --local.
```

And if I try either of these two:

```
luarocks --local install loadcaffe
sudo luarocks install loadcaffe
```

I get:

```
Error: No results matching query were found.
```

After relogging, this works as expected:

```
luarocks install loadcaffe
```

I've tried both `source ~/.bashrc` and running `torch-activate` directly, neither fix the problem.

Also tried:

- `bash -c luarocks install loadcaffe`,
- `screen luarocks install loadcaffe`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I played with it a bit but couldn't get it looking pretty!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command:

```
sudo luarocks --from=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/ install loadcaffe
```